# What is the manoeuvre point?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, stability

> a centre of gravity position at which stick force per g becomes zero

What does this mean? If the centre of gravity happened to be at the maneouvre point, would there be stick be very light in the hands? If this was the case would an aircraft be very responsive to stick inputs in pitch changes?

Comment: You should include the source of that statement.

Comment: @John K. Why? Seriously? It is a definition. It would be akin to giving a source to the definition of ‘centre of gravity.’

Comment: That's fine but you normally provide a link to where it was copy and pasted from, or a reference to the source just as a formality.  Like "Oxford Dictionary defines so and so as whatever....".  Someone may want to look up the material themselves for whatever reason.